# Insert trigger for duplicate records not working sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[STOK_HARKETLERI_Insert]    
ON [dbo].[STOK_HAREKETLERI]              
FOR INSERT 
AS BEGIN  
    declare @tip int 
    declare @miktar float 
    declare @stokkod nvarchar 
    declare @tarih datetime 
    declare @counter int  

    Select 
        @tip = sth_tip,  @miktar = sth_miktar,  
        @stokkod = sth_stok_kod, @tarih = sth_tarih 
    from inserted 

    select @Counter = COUNT(sth_tip) 
    from STOK_HAREKETLERI  
    where sth_evraktip = 6 
      and sth_tip = @tip 
      and sth_miktar = @miktar 
      and @stokkod = sth_stok_kod 
      and @tarih = sth_tarih   

    if (@counter>=1)  
    begin     
       rollback     
       RAISERROR ('Record already exists', 17, -1) with log 
    end    
END
GO
```

The trigger is not being triggered on insert statements, however if I remove the variables and fill the data and run it on SQL Server it is running fine.

Any suggestions?

One more thing if I change the line `(@counter >= 1)` to `(@counter >= 0)` it starts working again.

Comment: Trigger will not execute for each row, it is at statement level

Comment: Can you explain your statement please?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select? It's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing best done with a unique constraint?

Comment: @DavidFaber No, Why? Because there are many type of records in this table, which I don't want to stop, I wanted to stop only this one.

Comment: @marc_s For me it is working line by line now , I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert more than one row, there will be more than one row in "inserted", but you're only checking the last of them. It might be easier to make a check constraint, depending on what the rules regarding "sth_evraktip = 6 " actually are (can there be more rows done with update later etc).

With insert trigger something like this might work:

```
if exists (select 1 from inserted i
where exists(select 1 from STOK_HAREKETLERI S
where S.sth_evraktip = 6
and S.sth_tip = i.sth_tip
and S.sth_miktar = i.sth_miktar
and S.sth_stok_kod = i.sth_stok_kod
and S.sth_tarih = i.sth_tarih
and S.sth_RECno < i.sth_RECno)) begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('Record already exists', 17, -1) with log 
 end
```

If any of the columns can contain NULL, then you'll have to add more logic to handle that.

Comment: I am trying to insert only one line and it is failing.

Comment: What do mean by failing? Do you get an error or doesn't the check work?

Comment: No, It does not give the error, that is the issue my friend.

Comment: Added an example that should work, but sth_evraktip and  sth_RECno values can cause it to miss something, and NULLs are always something to look out for.

Answer (score -1):

If i skip the variable declaration and value passing to variable trigger works flawlessly.**FOR EACH LINE in my case**
Edited code is posted below.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[STOK_HARKETLERI_Insert]
   ON  [dbo].[STOK_HAREKETLERI]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
Declare @counter int

select @counter =  COUNT(sth_tip) from STOK_HAREKETLERI
where sth_evraktip = 6
and sth_tip = (select sth_tip from inserted i)
and sth_miktar =(select sth_miktar from inserted)
and sth_stok_kod =(select sth_stok_kod from inserted)
and sth_tarih = (select sth_tarih from inserted)
and sth_RECno < (select sth_RECno from inserted)

if (@counter>=1)

begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('Record already exists', 17, -1) with log
end


END
```